# Functional test of form Symfony3 mocked session

Tags: symfony, testing, phpunit

I'm writing functional tests for my symfony3 application and I have a problem that when I'm trying to test sending forms, by crawling the submit button.

Method what I want to test:

```
$personalDataForm->handleRequest($request);
if ($personalDataForm->isValid()) {
  return $this->handlePersonalForm($personalDataForm, $request);
}

return $this->render('members/personal-form.html.twig', [
  'personalDataForm' => $personalDataForm->createView(),
]);
```

Functional test:

```
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->getCookieJar()->set($this->cookie);
    $client->followRedirects();

    $container = $client->getContainer();
    $container->set('session', $this->session);

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');

    $form = $crawler->selectButton('Save')->form();
    $client->submit($form);
```

Declaration of `$this->session`:

```
$this->session = new Session(new MockArraySessionStorage(), new AttributeBag(), new FlashBag())
```

The crawler is correctly sending a request, but I have an error `Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "phar:///usr/local/bin/phpunit/phpunit/Util/Printer.php" at line 134.`

When I'm looking at test result I see that my test didn't pass the `$personalDataForm->isValid()` condition.

I think the problem is that after submitting form, application is using `Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/NativeSessionStorage` to store a session instead of mocked session. How can I pass mocked session when I'm submitting form?

Comment: where you have declared the session in this manner? The only conf regarding the session in the test env tha i have is in the config_test.yml files and is something like:     `session:
        storage_id: session.storage.mock_file`

Comment: try don't inject the session in the container in the test case

Comment: In the response is the same result, and now test returning "InvalidArgumentException: The current node list is empty" - it looks like that my crawler cannot receive a valid response data.

Comment: before check for page element please check the response is good. After the `GET /` make this assertion  `$this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode(), "Page ok");`

Comment: I'f I don't inject session in the container it returns false and code response is 500, with same error.